# Why does form collapse when specify LowerBound in javaFX AreaChart?

Tags: java, javafx-2

I want to specify that LowerBound variables(0>x) but the AreaChart become strange.
Please tell me this solution.

sorry.. i don't have reputation points.
If I got reputations points for uploading do that.

JavaFX version 2.2.51-b13

thank you

here is code:

```
public class chartApp extends Application{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage){

        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final AreaChart<Number, Number> areaChart = new AreaChart<Number, Number>(xAxis,yAxis);
        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();

        final Integer[] yData = {500,501,502,503,500,502,499,498};

        yAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
        yAxis.setUpperBound(520.d);
        yAxis.setLowerBound(480.d);

        for (int i = 0; i < yData.length; i++) {
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(i, yData[i]));
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(areaChart, 800, 600);
        areaChart.getData().add(series);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        System.out.println(com.sun.javafx.runtime.VersionInfo.getRuntimeVersion());


    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Area charts don't really make much sense (from a statistical perspective) when the axis doesn't include zero. This looks like [RT-34626](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-34626), which is fixed in the latest pre-release (JDK 8u20). I don't know of any work-around.

Comment: I tried latest version SDK but could not solve.
don't tried this patch file because not want to change modules.
switched to Line chart by this advice reference.
thank you.

Comment: It works for me in the [ea release](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html). But I think a line chart is a better option anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is bug in the Java 1.7.
I confirmed able to solve the latest version.
James_D, Thank you for advice.

[ea release](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html)
JDK 8u20 2014/04/17