# JavaFX AreaChart reversed masking

Tags: java, javafx-2, scenebuilder

I'm trying to create some stock charts in JavaFX/SceneBuilder, but when I draw it to an AreaChart, it looks like (see img) - the masked area have reversed ?

[image: pic]

```
series1 = new XYChart.Series();
series1.setName("XYChart.Series 1");
series1 = rtsd.getIntraSeries(15);
fxidSAC.getData().addAll(series1);
```

I have disabled ForceZeroInRange and enabled AutoRanging (on yAxis)

EDIT: After some further testing, it would seem enabling ForceZeroInRange makes the mask look normal, but how can I disable it, without screwing up the masking ?

Comment: Nothing is working! >.< Is this some kinda bug ?

Tried setting range to 12000 - 15000, ForceZeroInRange(true) - yet it still colors the wrong end of the chart -.-

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does form collapse when specify LowerBound in javaFX AreaChart?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074752/why-does-form-collapse-when-specify-lowerbound-in-javafx-areachart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people stumbling over this thread, the answer was to update to an Early Access JDK 8u20
see thread [Why does form collapse when specify LowerBound in javaFX AreaChart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074752/why-does-form-collapse-when-specify-lowerbound-in-javafx-areachart)

Comment: cough .. searching _before_ asking helps avoiding duplicates ;-) Thanks for the reference, though!